# Change value of object class in Hive using StateNotifier/ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I have a Hive box to save an *object class*, which is `InappPengguna` to save user info that would be in use for offline auto login. The value of `InappPengguna.status` is `UserStatus.loggedinSuccessfully` which generated from *Login Page*. Then at *Home Page*, I want to change the value of `InappPengguna.status` to `UserStatus.loggedin`, but my code doesn't work, the status still `UserStatus.loggedinSuccessfully`. How to do it programatically. Below is what I've tried. Thank you.

**Expected behaviour**

`Login [UserStatus.loggedinSuccessfully] -> Home [UserStatus.loggedinSuccessfully -> UserStatus.loggedin]`

**Obtained behaviour**

`Login [UserStatus.loggedinSuccessfully] -> Home [UserStatus.loggedinSuccessfully -> UserStatus.loggedinSuccessfully]`

```dart
class RepoInapp extends ChangeNotifier {
  final KontrolerDB db; // class for Hive.init()

  RepoInapp(this.db);

  InappPengguna getDataInapp() {
    final ip = db.boxInapp.get('inapp');
    return ip as InappPengguna;
  }

  Future<void> saveDataInapp(InappPengguna ip) async {
    await db.boxInapp.put('inapp', ip);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

final repoInappProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) {
  final db = ref.watch(providerDB);
  return RepoInapp(db);
});
```

```dart
class ChangeLoginStatusNotifier extends StateNotifier<InappPengguna> {
  ChangeLoginStatusNotifier(this.ip) : super(ip);

  final InappPengguna ip;

  changeStatus() async {
    state = ip;
    if (state.status != UserStatus.loggedin) {
      state.status = UserStatus.loggedin;
    }
    return state;
  }
}

final providerUbahStatusMasuk =
    StateNotifierProvider<ChangeLoginStatusNotifier, InappPengguna>((ref) {
  final ri = ref.read(repoInappProvider);
  return ChangeLoginStatusNotifier(ri.getDataInapp());
});

@HiveType(typeId: 4)
enum UserStatus {
  @HiveField(0)
  loggedin,
  @HiveField(1)
  loggedout,
  @HiveField(2)
  loggedinSuccessfully,
  @HiveField(3)
  loggedinFailure
}

@HiveType(typeId: 2)
class InappPengguna {
  @HiveField(0)
  PenggunaInapp? pengguna;
  @HiveField(1)
  DateTime? loginLama;
  @HiveField(2)
  DateTime? loginBaru;
  @HiveField(3)
  UserStatus? status;
  @HiveField(4)
  String? token;

  InappPengguna(
      {this.pengguna, this.loginLama, this.loginBaru, this.status, this.token});

      // parsing function from/to json
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `copyWith` method to your data model.

```dart
  InappPengguna copyWith({
    PenggunaInapp? pengguna,
    DateTime? loginLama,
    DateTime? loginBaru,
    UserStatus? status,
    String? token,
  }) {
    return InappPengguna(
      pengguna: pengguna ?? this.pengguna,
      loginLama: loginLama ?? this.loginLama,
      loginBaru: loginBaru ?? this.loginBaru,
      status: status ?? this.status,
      token: token ?? this.token,
    );
  }
```

Then change the `changeStatus` to the following, since `StateNotifier` notifies only when the state is assigned new value.

```dart
  changeStatus() {
    state = ip;

    if (state.status != UserStatus.loggedin) {
      state = state.copyWith(status: UserStatus.loggedin);
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your respon, I will consider change my code to simplify from your answer

Answer (score -1):

I've found a solution for my problem, it is by replacing `StateNotifier` with `NotifierProvider` which call `saveDataInapp` from `RepoInapp`, like this:

```dart
class ChangeLoginStatusNotifier extends Notifier<InappPengguna> {
  @override
  InappPengguna build() {
    final ip = ref.watch(repoInappProvider).getDataInapp();
    return ip;
  }

  changeStatus() => state.status = UserStatus.loggedin;

  void saveNewStatus() =>
      ref.watch(repoInappProvider.notifier).saveDataInapp(state);
}

final providerChangeLoginStatus =
    NotifierProvider<ChangeLoginStatusNotifier, InappPengguna>(() {
  return ChangeLoginStatusNotifier();
});
```